# PBR maps required for polished granite

Tags: texturing, materials, pbr

I need to texture a cube with polished granite. I applied my diffuse into the base color of the BSDF shader and set the roughness to 0. is that enough or do I need to add other maps like normal,AO and metallic?

Comment: If a polished look is your  goal, that should be sufficient, however, if you want photorealism, you might want to consider using a roughness map, so the surface isn't so perfectly "clean" - imperfections are the key to realism ;) Since the surface is totally flat, you shouldn't need to worry about normal maps or ambient occlusion either, and metallic is generally reserved for conductive materials (metals only),.

Comment: Since you're already using the BSDF, I would suggest turning the roughness way up (0.9ish) and adding "clearcoat" with a dirt map on the "clearcoat roughness" channel.